# Parameter space exploration

Tags: data-mining, pattern-recognition, multivariate-regression

*I do realise this question is quite specific and practical, but I seek for some general help which helps me progress further in my analysis.*

Let $y(\boldsymbol{x})\in\mathbb{R}$ be the function I'd like to regress, whereas $\boldsymbol{x}\in\mathbb{R}^6$. My design matrix $\boldsymbol{X}\in\mathbb{R}^{11\times6}$ (therefore, at the moment, $y(\boldsymbol{X})\in\mathbb{R}^{11}$, but I can run further experiments, if needed).
My aim is maximising $y(\boldsymbol{x})$ over $\boldsymbol{x}$, $x_{2k+1}=\{5,7,9\}$, $x_{2k}=\{2,4\}$.

If I would run a *dense* experimental analysis, I would to test $3^3\times2^3=216$ cases, and each of those are very time consuming.

The collected data is the following (yes, I know, they do not respect the constrain given above, which it allows me to run a reasonably lower total number of experiments if the *dense experimental analysis* will be considered as only feasible solution):

```
X = [
     4     2     3     2     3     2
     7     2     5     2     5     4
    10     2     7     4     5     2
    10     2     9     2     8     4
    10     4     6     2     4     2
     7     2     5     4     5     2
     7     4     5     2     5     2
     7     2     5     4     5     4
     7     4     5     2     5     4
     7     4     5     4     5     2
     7     4     5     4     5     4
     ];

y = [
     64.7
     68.0
     69.4
     68.5
     68.5
     71.9
     71.6
     71.7
     71.0
     71.6
     68.6
     ];
```

I did scatter plot $(x_i, y(x_i)),i=\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$, but the output is not that informative.

```
name = {
     'ks1'
     'ss1'
     'ks2'
     'ss2'
     'ks3'
     'ss3'
     };

[m, n] = size(X); % # of experiments, # of parameters = 3 conv kernel size + 3 subsamp

for j = 1:2:n
    subplot(2,3,(j+1)/2)
    h = plot(X(:,j),y,'x','MarkerSize',10,'LineWidth',2);
    xlabel(name{j})
    ylabel('Testing accuracy [%]')
    axis([2 10 60 75])
    grid on
end

for j = 2:2:n
    subplot(2,3,3+j/2)
    h = plot(X(:,j),y,'x','MarkerSize',10,'LineWidth',2);
    xlabel(name{j})
    ylabel('Testing accuracy [%]')
    axis([1 5 60 75])
    grid on
end
```

[image: Scatter plots]

So, my question is, **how can I understand** (and/or visualise) **what is going on in this multivariate problem?**
To my mind a PCA keeps coming up as possible useful tool, even though I know it is used for visualising main orientations rather than helping me finding the maxima of my scalar fields..

**Update**
I am currently running the 216 cases batch experiment, limited to 30 epochs training. Still, I would like to *visualise* my results. Actually, I do have a testing (and training) accuracy function per case, whereas above I just picked its maximum.

This is an overview of the testing accuracy functions
[image: Testing accuracies]

---

What I am trying to accomplish is determining the best configuration for a convolutional artificial neural network. The parameters I am considering here are *kernel size* (`ks`) and *subsamplig* (`ss`) factor for multiple layers (`1`, `2` and `3`), whereas $y(\cdot)$ is the testing (or cross-validation) accuracy.